# randrange() not working on my random_string() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

My random string function:

```
def random_string(chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
    size = random.randrange(10, 15)
    return str(''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size)))
```

I want it to generate random strings between 10 and 15 characters in length, hence why I have done `size = random.randrange(10, 15)`. However it doesn't abide by this rule.

Also, about 20% of the time, `random_string()` just returns an empty string: `''`. Not sure why this is.

Any one have any idea how to fix these problems?

Comment: "*However it doesn't abide by this rule*" Can you give us some examples of this kind? Because your code seems fine.

Comment: As in it generates strings lower than 10 characters.

Comment: There is no reason why this function would ever return an empty string, or a string whose length isn't between 10 and 15. The problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: If you're on python3.6, you can use `random.choices`: `''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=15))`

Comment: use random.choices for strings. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html. Also tried your code and I don't see why it should return an empty string

Comment: Work perfectly for me -- placed it through vigorous testing (i.e. a `for` loop generating 1000 random strings) and it worked every time.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnFUs.png).

Comment: We need a [mcve]. The code you've posted doesn't contain anything that would cause the behavior described.

Comment: Yeah I restarted my server and it works fine now...not sure what was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vigorous testing using the following program shows that the function works just fine:

```
import random, string

def random_string(chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
    size = random.randrange(10, 15)
    return str(''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size)))

for i in range(10000):
    x = random_string()
    if not (10 <= len(x) <= 15): #Check that the length of the 
                                 #generated string is within range

        print("Failed: len={0}".format(len(x)))

print("Tests completed")
```

Comment: You didn't really need to write an answer saying that. There are, like, 10 comments already affirming that.

Comment: Just was showing exactly how I tested it -- I also left a comment